# why contend not display (hide below header )in ionic (ion-contend not work properly )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to make simple first application in ionic .I am able to make footer and header .but when i added contend in **ion-contend** tag my contend not display .when i inspect it is below the header why ? It should be below header .How I will achieve to show ionic contend below header ?

how to add background image in ion-view  ?
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvYdNM

```
 <ion-view>
      <ion-header-bar class=" bar bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>    

      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <h1>contend</h1>
          </ion-content>
          <ion-footer-bar class=" bar bar-footer bar-positive">
           <h1 class="title">Fotter!</h1>
          </ion-footer-bar>
      </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 <ion-content>
```

by (add class):

```
 <ion-content class="has-header">
```